# Popup menu doesnt work when dockerized

Tags: angular, docker, primeng

I have a very strange issue. I have an angular app using a p-menu from Primeng for a popup menu in a row of a p-table.

All works fine when I run my app with ng serve. But unfortunately the popup menu doesnt show up anymore when I dockerize my app. Everything else is working find - only my p-menu doesnt show up anymore!

Any idea?

Her my docker file:

```
FROM node:8.11.3 as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/

RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/

ARG env=prod

RUN npm run build --prod --environment $env

FROM nginx:latest

VOLUME ["/usr/share/nginx/html","/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

WORKDIR /etc/nginx

COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Update:** After upgrading my angular project with npm update --save also running my app with ng serve doest work anymore. Seems docker already used new sources and therefore the issue.

Now I have to find out why p-menu from primeng doesnt work anymore in the latest release.

**FINAL UPDATE:**

The issue was docker used the newest version of the primeng library while I was still one version behind with my development environment. I had some styles in some CSS files which didnt work with primeng and caused an issue in the new version from primeng.

Comment: Can you share how you are creating docker image for your Angular app? While browsing the dockerized app have you checked the browser console for any errors?

Comment: Hi my docker file is pretty straight forward - I can cut and paste into my question. No errors in browser console. And its so weired - everything else works only popup menus dont work acrross the whole application!

Comment: Perhaps the only difference it that I use nginx when working with the dockerized version and I dont use nginx when starting it plain - but this shouldnt make any difference.

Comment: Have you checked the browser Network tab for any failing resource requests e.g. javascript or css? Another difference is that inside docker you are running prod build version of your app while when you run using ng serve its dev build

Comment: Hi - also started ng serve with --prod and didnt make a difference. No failing resource requests.

Comment: Can you try `ng serve --aot` and see if it reproduces the problem on your development environment

Comment: Tried - it still works with ng serve --aot but doesnt work in Docker. And the strage thing - the only thing that doesnt work is mein p-menu! Everything else seems to work perfectly fine!!!

Comment: Please move your final edit to an answer

Answer (score 1):

In the final segment of your Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
VOLUME ["/usr/share/nginx/html"]
COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

The `VOLUME` directive tells Docker two things.  One is that the directory contains data that should be implicitly persisted between container executions, whether or not the caller requests it.  The second is that the directory will never be changed again, and [Docker will ignore any changes in the volume directory after you declare it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes).

In practice, `VOLUME` is kind of tricky and any directories you'd want persisted you'd specify with a `docker run -v` or Docker Compose `volumes:` directive in any case.  (Directories that get mounted this way don't need to be pre-declared in the Dockerfile.)  I'd just delete the `VOLUME` line.

Comment: Yes - I still had this in there for some testing reasons. But removing this doesnt make a change - I still have ni popup menus in the docker version but it works perfectly find with ng serve

Answer (score 0):

The issue was docker used the newest version of the primeng library while I was still one version behind with my development environment. I had some styles in some CSS files which didnt work with primeng and caused an issue in the new version from primeng.